# Youtube upload API : Videos automatically private

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube API to upload videos.

The videos are uploaded public, but after the upload, they automatically changed to Private.

I've done the approval from the developer console, so the youtube.upload scope has been approved already. I'm only using the scope to upload and nothing else.

Any ideas ? I tried to contact the support, but no luck :(

Edit:

**My application has been verified:**
[image]

**And I have the correct scope:**
[image]

And the code:

```
let oauth = Youtube.authenticate({
  type: "oauth",
  client_id:
    "client",
  client_secret: "secret",
  redirect_url: "redirect",
});
    oauth.setCredentials(token);
Youtube.videos.insert(
      {
        resource: {

          snippet: {
            title: `blabla`,
            description: `blabla`,
          },

          status: {
            privacyStatus: "public",
            madeForKids: true,
          },
        },

        part: "snippet,status",

        media: {
          body: fs.createReadStream(`blabla.mp4`),
        },
      },
      (err, data) => {
        console.log("Done.");
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

[Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

[image]

When your application is still in the testing phase and has not been verified by google yet all videos uploaded will be uploaded as private.

Once you have set your application to published and gone though the verification process you will then be abled to upload public videos.

[image]

- [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)
- [YouTube API Services Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service)
- [July 28, 2020](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_07_28_2020)

[image]

## update

Audit is not verification, these are two different things. You need to apply for an audit. [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)

Comment: But my application has been verified!

Comment: I would check again that its still verified and set to production.   If it is please post your code.

Comment: I updated the original question to add the screenshots and the code I'm using

Comment: I would bug report it see what google says https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm reporting it

Comment: @GuillaumeC what is the last situation?

Comment: @AteşDanış I contacted youtube via the form, they said everything is working ok, and they don't know why I have the error, so I gave up.

Comment: Are you having the same issue ?

Comment: interesting. mine is not verified yet, sorry :/